# How to use AngularJS Material with AngularJS 1.2.20

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I tried to install the latest AngularJS Material version with this [Getting Started](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started) Guide on my AngularJS 1.2.20 Project. (I know its old, but I can't update)

```
Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/$injector/modulerr?p0=...
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js:6:450
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js:34:97
    at Array.forEach ()
    at q (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js:7:280)
    at e (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js:33:207)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js:33:284
    at Array.forEach ()
    at q (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js:7:280)
    at e (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js:33:207)
    at dc (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js:36:309
```

I don't know why, but I can't find any kind of list which version is compatible...

Maybe someone got an idea?

**This is how I include the js file in `<head>`**

```
<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

**Here is my angular.module:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngMaterial',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute',
    'infinite-scroll',
    'rzModule',
    'ngReallyClickModule',
    'ngVideoCutModule',
    'ngVideoTrailerModule',
    'ngItemModules',
    'ngDirectives',
    'xeditable',
    'monospaced.elastic',
    'angularFileUpload',
    'angulartics',
    'angulartics.google.analytics',
    'angular-video',
    'checklist-model',
    'ui-notification',
    'luegg.directives',
    'ngLoadingModule'
]);
```

**Include Order of JS Files:**

```
<script src="/inc/assets/js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.1/jquery.lazyload.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="/inc/js/app/application.js"></script>
<script src="/inc/js/app/app.routes.js"></script>
<script src="/inc/js/app/app.config.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Comment: post edited with angular.module

Comment: @Budi and your HTML please

Comment: only html is the <script> that i load in the <head> area. I edited post. I still dont copy demo html code from the angular material website.

Comment: `ng-app=""` please

Comment: @Zooly <html lang="de" ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl"> or what you need? (Sorry im not familiar with angular1 i work normaly with angular 5...

Comment: Remove all dependencies except ngMaterial and check?

Comment: Then i still got the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in [bower.json](https://github.com/angular/bower-material/blob/master/bower.json) and [package.json](https://github.com/angular/bower-material/blob/master/package.json) AngularJS 1.4 is the oldest version that we officially support with our latest releases. The reality is that 1.5+ is recommended. We'll be moving to 1.6 soon.

Note that `1.2.20` came out on Jul 11, 2014 and is lacking many security patches. If you must be on 1.2.x, you should at least be on `1.2.32` which includes fixes and security patches and was released on Oct 11, 2016.

I highly recommend upgrading to the latest AngularJS 1.6 as 1.7 is coming out this summer and will include LTS. You'll want your active projects to be on the LTS moving forward as critical fixes and security patches will only be applied to AngularJS 1.7.x.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding discussion in question comments, I think your error is that your declare your application (and your controller) before loading AngularJS scripts.

I recommend you to do that this way:

```
<html>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

First load AngularJS, then your custom scripts, and declare your app (in view) and then your controller.

Comment: Thanks for this fast information. I tested this but i still get the same error + "can not find module" error... I load atm all javascript files in the footer.php

I update the Topic Post with Include orders of Important files.

Comment: Not sure to understand why you are talking about PHP?

Comment: Its a project where we use php files.

Comment: Ok! Anyway, include angular.material.js before your custom scripts (/inc)

Comment: Loaded now direct after angular-route.js but still same error. I try allready alot loading positions =) is it possible that angular material dont work with angular 1.2.20?

Comment: Indeed it's not working for me too. Seems to be because of missing Angular Aria, that has been included in 1.3.0

Comment: Thank you for your commitment! I saw your issue post in the material issue board =)

I tryed the first version of angular material to, but this one didnt work to. Any idea how i can make this stuff running?

Comment: The only way I see it could properly work would be to upgrade your AngularJS version. Do it without breaking the rest of ur app ^

Comment: Impossible... Hmm okay thanks. then i need to rebuild material by my self for this old angular version :P

Comment: Yes of course I understand that you can’t upgrade easily! Have fun!